# Error on Installing Multibit for Windows 7?

Tags: client, multibit

I recently found about Bitcoin through a friend and got interested to surf about it over the Internet. I was installing Multibit on my machine running on Windows 7 but as soon as I click on the downloaded file, I get the following error.

This forum is not letting me attach an image so i have to manually type in the text :S

"Error:java.lang.AbstractMethodError:org.apache.xecres.dom.DocumentImpl.setXmlVersion(Ljava/lang/String;)V"

Please help me fix it !

Regards, Maddy

Comment: This sort of question is best directed at the [GitHub issues page for MultiBit](https://github.com/jim618/multibit/issues) rather than here. However, since Jim has answered illustrating a general JVM problem then perhaps it should remain open for others to use.

Answer (score 2):

Googling for that error there is a similar one at:
http://trac.jajuk.info/ticket/1549

There they suggest it could be something to do with the installed Java Runtime Environment. This is what the installer uses to run.

You could try making sure the Java installation on your machine is 100% by installing the latest version from:
 http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp

Then try the installer again.